# Qual o real beneficio de utilizar Controller Resource no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Qual o real beneficio de utilizar Controller Resource no Laravel? É possível observar que o arquivo de rotas fica mais limpo, já que os métodos do controller são chamados com base nas rotas e verbos de chamada, mas o único beneficio seria organização?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O benefício do uso de controladores do tipo recurso está na própria declaração e no contexto.

Visto que esse tipo de declaração de rota única cria várias rotas para manipular uma variedade de ações de uma requisição HTTP.

E por convenção, o controlador do tipo recurso já oferece todas as ações nomeadas de maneira que contextualize com as ações executadas na criação, atualização, consulta e deleção de dados.

Ainda sim pode se dizer que o controlador do tipo recurso é uma estrutura de dados pré-definida para gerenciar operações comuns de CRUD. (Create, Read, Update, Delete)